# How can I include an additional file in the scripts folder that "sbt dist" generates inside target/universal?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

Running sbt dist yields an output that looks like this:

```
    project_dir 
  | 
  |--- target/universal
          |
          |
          |
          | --- scripts
          |        |
          |        |--- blah.bat
          |        |--- blah (.sh file)
          |
          | --- blah-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip (entire package zipped)
```

How do I go about copying a file so that it ends up in the target/universal/scripts folder? Any "mappings in Universal" tricks I tried resulted in the files I was copying ending up in the zip.

An example of what didn't work:

```
mappings in Universal ++=(baseDirectory.value / "scripts" * "*" get) map (x => x -> { x.setExecutable(true); baseDirectory.value.toString + "/test/" +  x.getName;} )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you have two questions. First

> How do I go about copying a file so that it ends up in the target/universal/scripts folder

This is most likely not what you want. The `target/universal/scripts` folder is nothing but a temporary folder were the scripts are generated before being zipped.

You can create files in arbitrary directories with a few lines of scala

```
lazy val writeSomeFiles = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Creates some files")
writeSomeFiles := {
  // `target/universal` folder
  val universalTarget = (target in Universal).value

  val sourceFiles = (baseDirectory.value ** AllPassFilter).get
  val destFiles = sourceFiles.map(file =>  universalTarget / file.getNamae)

  IO.copy(sourceFiles.zipWith(destFiles))

  destFiles
}
```

See: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/io/AllPassFilter$.html
See: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/io/IO$.html

Second:

> Any "mappings in Universal" tricks I tried resulted in the files I was copying ending up in the zip

That's exactly what the `mappings in Universal` are. The content of your created package (in this case as zip file). The `dist` (or `universal:packageBin`) task returns exactly one file, which is the created zip file.

If you plan to ship your package then this is the correct way to handle things.

hope that helps,
Muki

Comment: Thanks Muki - the reason I am trying to copy an additional script into the scripts folder is because I need a script that will unzip the package, update symlinks and do some post deploy activities. I want this script to be under source control as well and also deployed as part of the project.